# Bokeh plot not visible in flask application

Tags: python, nginx, flask, jinja2, bokeh

This is a flask application which usually works.

My plots generated with bokeh are not showing up on the page at all. I can see that they are added to the html when I look with the tools but they're not visible. The page does not break and I can visit it as normal. I have tried everything from their page but now I just want the simplest example to work. When applied the json variant I just got a json printed on the page where the plot's supposed to be.

What have I missed?

EDIT: A minimum working example is also apreciated.

My route

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash
import json

from bokeh.embed import json_item, server_document, components
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers

from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import BoxSelectTool, LassoSelectTool
from bokeh.client import pull_session

test_bp = Blueprint(
    'test_bp', __name__,
    template_folder='templates',
    static_folder='static'
)


@test_bp.route('/test_site', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_site_view():
    plot = figure()
    plot.circle([1, 2], [3, 4])
    script, div = components(plot)
    
    return render_template(
        'test.html',
        script=script,
        div=div
    )
```

My test.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<header>
  {{ script|safe }}
</header>

{% block content %}
<h1>Plot</h1>
<div>
  {{ div|safe }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html includes

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.1.0.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.1.0.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-2.1.0.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" />
</head>
```

Comment: Do you actually have version 2.1 of the Python library installed? The CDN version has to match the Python version. Are there any errors or messages on the browser JS console?

Comment: How can I check that the correct py library is installed?

Comment: Only errors I see are "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you are trying to load CDN resources that don't actually exists. Bokeh stopped publishing separate CSS files at version 2.0. Since it is important that the CDN and Python versions match, it's best to just always let Bokeh itself format the necessary resources:

```py
@test_bp.route('/test_site', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_site_view():
    plot = figure()
    plot.circle([1, 2], [3, 4], size=40)
    script, div = components(plot)

    return render_template(
        'test.html',
        script=script,
        div=div,
        resources=CDN.render()
    )
```

works with this template:

```html
<head>
  {{ resources|safe }}
</head>

<header>
  {{ script|safe }}
</header>

{% block content %}
<h1>Plot</h1>
<div>
  {{ div|safe }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]